# I can't access this method of my ViewController

Tags: ios, nsnotifications

This is the result of selected checkbox and I need to access that method to block all others checkboxes.

I received this error:

```
-[UIView removeTarget]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6aeded0
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:'-[UIView removeTarget]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6aeded0'

-(void)checked:(NSNotification *)notif {
    for (int i = 0; i < [[[[[[[[[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:1] subviews] objectAtIndex:4]subviews] count]; i++) 
    {
        AskViewController *askView = ((AskViewController *)[[[[[[[[[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:2] subviews] objectAtIndex:0] subviews] objectAtIndex:4]subviews] objectAtIndex:i]);
        [askView removeTarget];
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean that you "can't access" it???  What can't you access?  What tells you you can't?  Are there any error messages?  Is there any reason why, if there are, you didn't list them here like you're supposed to?

Comment: [UIView removeTarget]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6aeded0
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView removeTarget]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6aeded0'

Comment: This seems an overly complex way of disabling other checkboxes on a page. Relying upon the index of subviews to target a specific set of them is risky.

Comment: @virorum -- Yep, it's kinda like Russian roulette.  At least he's only aiming at his foot.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to execute removeTarget on an object (UIView) that does not support that method.